# Erro com hibernate ao executar servidor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Ao executar o wildfly estou com o seguinte trecho de erro no log:

```
15:46:18,297 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."evolutionary.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."evolutionary.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type EntityManager with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject br.com.evolutionary.negocio.HabilidadeDAO.em
  at br.com.evolutionary.negocio.HabilidadeDAO.em(HabilidadeDAO.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

A classe que ele acusa o erro é:

```
package br.com.evolutionary.negocio;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import br.com.evolutionary.modelo.Habilidade;

public class HabilidadeDAO implements DAO<Habilidade, String> {

    @Inject
    EntityManager em;
    @Inject
    private Logger log;


    public Habilidade insert(Habilidade x) throws Exception {
    log.info("Persistindo " +x);
        em.persist(x);
        return x;
    }

    public Habilidade update(Habilidade x) throws Exception {
        log.info("Atualizando..." +x);
        return em.merge(x);

    }

    public void delete(Habilidade x) throws Exception {
        em.remove(x);

    }

    public Habilidade find(String y) throws Exception {
        log.info("Procurando...."+y);
        return em.find(Habilidade.class, y);
    }

}
```

Pelo que entendi falta dependências ainda. Depois não consegui mais andar. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Ao que me parece, o cdi não está conseguindo injetar a EntityManager no seu dao, você anotou o método que gera a EntityManager com @Produces?

Comment: @Geferson era exatamente isso. Se quiser formalizar a resposta, eu valido em seguida...Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A injeção de dependências do CDI, funciona basicamente ligando "Produtor" x "Dependente", no seu DAO, nessa linha:

```
@Inject
EntityManager em;
```

Você estava solicitando ao servidor que injetasse um instância de EntityManager, porém, para isso funcionar, necessitaria informar ao CDI qual é o método Produtor/Gerador dessa dependência.

O Cdi percorre todos os objetos passíveis de injeção e verifica se algum deles atende a dependência solicitada.

> Como Resolver?

No seu método que gera as instâncias de EntityManager, anote com @Produces.

```
@Produces
public EntityManager getEM(){...}
```

Feito isso, resolve o problema.

Nos servidores de aplicação java(Glassfish, JBOSS, etc..), você também pode Injetar um EntityManager diretamente sem escrever o método, dessa forma:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "NomeDoPU")
private EntityManager em;
```

Assim não precisa utilizar @Inject/Produces.